# In Android (Galaxy S), is there a way to automatically sync photos from camera to picasa?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sync, photos, picasa

I want to have it so that when I take a picture it automatically syncs to a private folder in picasa, is there a native way to do this? or maybe a third party way?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can sync automatically on the Galaxy S at present but I understand it is [supported in Froyo](https://web.archive.org/web/20110812080935/http://crave.cnet.co.uk:80/mobiles/android-22-froyo-vs-android-21-eclair-vs-android-15-cupcake-speed-taste-49305763/) which is [apparently](https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/reviews/samsung/71896-samsung-galaxy-s-phone-review) coming to the Galaxy S soon. In the meantime there is an app or two that does this.

[PicPush](http://blog.350nice.com/wp/products/picpush) has a free 30 day trial, then costs $4.99. QRCode for the Android Market below

[image: PicPush QRCode]
<sub>(source: [350nice.com](http://blog.350nice.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/picpush_qr-150x150.png))</sub>

[Docs Pics](https://web.archive.org/web/20120706094829/http://www.androidzoom.com:80/android_applications/tools/docs-pics_gjeo.html) apparently does a load of things including syncing files to Picasa. It is free.

[image: Doc Pics QRCode]

I've not used either app yet. I'll update if I get a chance to try them.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is now possible if you sign up to Google+.

Install the [Google+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus&feature=search_result) app. Open it. Then under Menu->Settings there is an Instant Upload option with the following description: "Automatically upload new photos & videos to a private web albumn."

There are also a bunch of settings to control it under Instant Upload Settings.

When you activate this and take some photos, they come up under an Instant Upload album in Picasa.

Comment: In reality Google should have built 2-way sync into Picasa from the start.

Comment: Absolutely. I've heard rumours that it is coming in Android 3.0 but not sure.